# AttributeError at /accounts/signup/ 'str' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, django

Am new using django so i used practical example on this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)  on extending user model using User Profile, am having trouble on form.py it gives that error, on removing this line;
supervisor.su_mobile_number.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('su_mobile_number'))
it works smoothly but no data for su_mobile_number was inserted o the database

**view.py**

```
class SupervisorSignUpView(CreateView):
     model = User
     form_class = SupervisorSignUpForm
     template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['user_type'] = 'supervisor'
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user)
    return redirect('home')
```

**model.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Supervisor(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='supervisor')
   su_mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SupervisorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
 su_mobile_number = forms.CharField()

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User

@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.is_supervisor = True
    user.save()
    supervisor = Supervisor.objects.create(user=user)
    supervisor.su_mobile_number.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('su_mobile_number'))
    return user
```

Comment: `su_mobile_number` field is a `CharField`. What you are trying to do with `supervisor.su_mobile_number.add`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, thanks for the reply, i want to save it to db after creating user associated with it

Comment: `supervisor = Supervisor.objects.create(user=user, su_mobile_number=self.cleaned_data.get('su_mobile_number')))` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`=`** operator to assign value and then call **`save()`** method

```
@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.is_supervisor = True
    user.save()
    supervisor = Supervisor.objects.create(user=user)
    supervisor.su_mobile_number = self.cleaned_data.get('su_mobile_number')
    supervisor.save()
    return user
```

---

**more shorter way is** (as [@Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m)  mentioned)

```
@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.is_supervisor = True
    user.save()
    supervisor = Supervisor.objects.create(user=user, su_mobile_number=self.cleaned_data.get('su_mobile_number'))
    return user
```